# Django templates - Reusable fragment with flexible name

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a reusable HTML fragment that I use to list items. So to list items in a view I just do:

```
variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'items': items,
}
return render_to_response('template_in_question',variables)
```

and the fragment is:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <p>Item: {{item.name}} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

So far so good. However, there are views where I want to use the same reusable fragment twice. For example, if I want to list the most sold items and the latest items, I need to create two copies of that reusable fragment:

The view would be like this:

```
variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'most_sold_items': most_sold_items,
    'latest_items': latest_items
}
```

and in the HTML would need to have two reusable HTML templates:

```
{% for item in most_sold_items %}
     <p>Item: {{item.name}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

and a second one

```
 {% for item in latest_items %}
     <p>Item: {{item.name}}</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

So my question is: How can I use, in the same view, two or more item lists, and use a common HTML template for that? For example, in the view above pass "most_sold_items" and "latest_items" and somehow use just one HTML template to list each separately?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it with the include tag. Basically, you'd end up with:

```
<h1>Most sold items</h1>
{% include "items.html" with items=most_sold_items only %}

<h1>Latest items</h1>
{% include "items.html" with items=latest_items only %}
```